# DB connection with encrypted password

Tags: java, database, spring, password-encryption

For making the database connection in spring 3 i use xml which have defined bean

```
<bean id="griffDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${DRIVER_CLASS}" p:jdbcUrl="${DB_URL}"
p:minPoolSize="${MIN_DB_POOL_SIZE}" p:maxPoolSize="${DB_POOL_SIZE}"
p:maxStatements="${DB_POOL_SIZE}"p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="${IDLE_CONNECTION_TEST_PERIOD}"p:loginTimeout="${LOGIN_TIMEOUT}" scope="singleton"></bean>
```

here DB_URL value is read from property file

```
DB_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseautoReconnect=true&user=root&password= [B@42e21073
```

This password in `url` is encrypted using `AES`.
The requirement is that i should write a code that when spring go for making the connection to the database it should itself decrypt the password and make the connection.
 How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I have used BASE64Encoder & BASE64Decoder. later You will modify my code to use a secure/better encryption/decryption algorithm.

You first  encoded your database password by using the below code:

```
private String encode(String str) {
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        str = new String(encoder.encodeBuffer(str.getBytes()));
        return str;
    }
```

Now You use wrapper class for org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource and overridden setPassword() method:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

public class MyCustomBasicDataSource extends BasicDataSource{



    public synchronized void setPassword(String encodedPassword){
        this.password = decode(encodedPassword);
    }

    private String decode(String password) {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        String decodedPassword = null;
        try {
            decodedPassword = new String(decoder.decodeBuffer(password));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return decodedPassword;
    }
}
```

This way You can decoding(BASE64Decoder) the encoded password .

Comment: Thanks for the help.But here combopooleddatasource is final class and it can't be extended.